# Fixed distance buffer is missing in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, buffer, geoprocessing, polygon-creation

I know it's an early adopter version, but does anyone know why my regular buffer tool is missing in QGIS 3.0? Possibly others too.

p.s.: I have already tried the other missing feature fix of deleting `.qgis2` folder

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can find it (filtering by buffer) at Processing Toolbox (SAGA provider).

Comment: Always look in the Processing toolbox, all algorithms are there. Menus like "Vector" and "raster" are mainly shortcuts to the processing toolbox.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the native QGIS's ["Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) tool in the Vector Geometry menu of the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

For me, it was MUCH faster than the SAGA's "Fixed distance buffer" tool.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find it (filtering by buffer) at Processing Toolbox (SAGA provider):

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use the SAGA provider. Better to use the native "Buffer" algorithm, the first item in your screenshot.