# Creating inset of the polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing, buffer, polygon-creation

How to create an inset of a polygon?

Not just visually but as a new polygon. For example - I have a yellow polygon and need to create a green one:

Looking for a solution in QGIS.

[image: example]

Comment: So, you're asking how to create a negative buffer?

Comment: @Erik Yes. And thanks for improving my terminology. My term "inset" was taken from Inkscape.

Comment: That wasn't about improving your terminology, that also was the solution ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was with the terminology and the correct word for *"inset"* is *"negative buffer"*.

Use the ["Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) tool in QGIS: `Vector / Geoprocessing tools / Buffer` ... and enter negative distance.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally I may suggest using the SAGA's ["Features Buffer"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/shapes_tools_18.html) (a.k.a. "Fixed Distance Buffer"). Look for it in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

There you will have a possibility to create an *'Inner Buffer'* i.e. a Negative Buffer.

[image: example]

---

**References:**

- [Fixed distance buffer is missing in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276551/fixed-distance-buffer-is-missing-in-qgis-3)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively in QGIS, use a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`. With the SQLite script in the form window <Resquest>-<Add>:

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT MakePolygon(InteriorRingN(geometry, 1)) geom
FROM
    <table_name>
```

You'll get the result you need.