# Polygonize area surrounded by buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, gpx, polygonize

I have an automated system in QGIS that separates loops from GPX traces and works out their centroid using 'Polygonize' >> 'Keep N biggest parts' >> 'Centroids'.

However, quite often it includes part of the 'loop approach' in the polygon:

[image: GPX trace]

[image: Polygon]

This distorts the centroid calculation.

I think there might be a way to use a line buffer to separate the loop from the GPX trace. I don't care about preserving the GPX data but I want to avoid 'dangles'.

I can use a buffer to make a polygon around the GPX trace:
[image: Buffered line]

But I cannot work out how to make the area inside the 'buffer polygon' (shown in yellow) into a separate polygon that I can use to calculate the centroid.

[image: Inner polygon]

It is essential that the process can be automated. I have hundreds of files that need to be processed.

Negative buffers don't help:

[image]

They change the buffer but don't make a polygon from the area surrounded by the buffered line.

But maybe I am missing something.

here is the GPX trace for the simple square so you can test it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" creator="Open GPX Tracker for iOS">
    
        <trk>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="100.000" lon="100.000">
                
            </trkpt>
            
            <trkpt lat="100.000" lon="200.000">
                
            </trkpt>

            <trkpt lat="200.000" lon="200.000">
                
            </trkpt>

            <trkpt lat="200.000" lon="100.000">
                
            </trkpt>

            <trkpt lat="100.000" lon="100.000">
                
            </trkpt>
            
        </trkseg>
    </trk>  
</gpx>
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/366701/120129...check this link, maybe it will fit...

Comment: Agreed, just negative buffer that polygon, rather than buffering the line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. First I buffer the GPX trace with +0.0001° (in this case) to make the 'buffer polygon' and then buffer the 'buffer polygon' with -00001° to make the 'loop polygon'?

Comment: Play negative values upwards so that they tighten the hole, for example: - 0.1 ° и т.д....

Comment: Don't forget that I start with a line. The first buffer puffs up the line to make a new polygon (the buffer polygon). When I apply a negative buffer to this 'buffer polygon' it makes a smaller buffer - around the same line. I can't see how it will help me make a polygon out of the area defined by the loop. The area I am interested in is outside the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

1. 'Polygonize' the line first
2. 'Negative buffer' this polygonized layer
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]